# Calculating CTR / eCPM and other values inside a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with a PostgreSQL database that logs the activity of an ad server. The ad_tracker table has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE ad_tracker (
  created_at timestamp,
  type smallint, // type can be 0 for impression 1 for click, 2 for purchase
  ad_unit_id integer,
  advertiser_id integer,
  price integer,
  rate integer
);
```

I need to write a query to calculate the Click-Through Rate (CTR) and revenue for each ad unit. The type field indicates whether a log entry is an impression (0), click (1), or purchase (2). The formula for CTR is the percentage of clicks among impressions, and revenue is calculated as the sum of purchases multiplied by the price and rate.

```
SELECT
  ad_unit_id,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 0) AS impressions,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 1) AS clicks,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 2) AS conversions,
  (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 1) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 0)) AS ctr,
  (COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 2) * price * 1.0 / 100) AS revenue
FROM
  ad_tracker
GROUP BY
  ad_unit_id;
```

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient or accurate way to calculate these metrics. I would appreciate any suggestions or improvements on this query and whether there are better practices for achieving the desired results.

I have also tried the following, but it gives me wrong calculations:

```
WITH TotalsCte AS (
  SELECT
    ad_unit_id,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE type IN (0, 4)) AS impressions,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 2) AS clicks,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 3) AS conversions
  FROM
    raw_event
  GROUP BY
    ad_unit_id
)

SELECT
  re.ad_unit_id,
  TCTE.impressions,
  TCTE.clicks,
  TCTE.conversions,
  (TCTE.clicks * 100.0 / NULLIF(TCTE.impressions, 0)) AS ctr,
  (re.price / 100.0) AS cpm,
  (TCTE.conversions * re.price * (1 - re.commission / 100.0) / 100.0) AS revenue
FROM
  raw_event re
JOIN
  TotalsCte TCTE ON re.ad_unit_id = TCTE.ad_unit_id;
```